# Prerequisites issue with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I am trying to distribute an application using ClickOnce, to get prerequisites installed I have followed instructions from *[How to: Include Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

So I ended up with the following:

[image]

Prerequisites were copied to the corresponding package folder:

[image]

When I want to publish it fails with three exceptions:

1. To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine.
2. To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine.
3. To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlExpress2012\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server 2012 Express' to your local machine.

From the above, it is evident to me that some additional steps need to be done, but the documentation fails to be explicit. Hopefully someone have come across with this before. Any clue?

Comment: 1) Have you also set the .NET Framework 4 (4.5?) as a prerequisite? 2/3) Have you included the prerequisites as items in your project, and marked them to be downloaded with the application?  if they're not downloaded to the client machine it will not be able to run them

Comment: @Jonnus, Framework 4.5 and SqExpress are my only prerequisites. Those errors comes out when I try to publish

Comment: Have you included the prerequisites as **items in your project**, and marked them to be downloaded with the application?  if they're not downloaded to the client machine it will not be able to run them

Comment: @Jonnus I included the prerequisites as showed in the first screenshot, apart of that I don't did anything else.